# VAC service charge for online applicants for Canadian Visa

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork

I have submitted my application for Canadian Visa online. Now they are asking me to send them my passport along with other documents like Consent form etc, which are listed in documents checklist provided at their website.

In the documents checklist there is a VAC service charge (if applicable). VAC stands for Visa Application Charge. As I have submitted my application online through MyCIC account, I want to know, do I need to submit VAC service charge as well?

Comment: Sorry, what's VAC ?

Comment: What do the instructions say?  Also, where are you applying from?

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to submit the application without them asking you for payment. I just went through the steps and they clearly ask you how you intend to pay, did you hit that step ?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, you only need to submit proof of payment for them to verify. The online payment page should have generated some sort of receipt for you to submit with the application

Comment: i have payed the visa application charge, which is CAD 100. But VAC charge is different https://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_application_processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VAC stands for Visa Application Center and not Charges.
As far as i know, you can either apply though VAC offices or online. If you apply online you won't need to pay the VAC charges.

I applied online and only paid for the VISA + Biometrics fees.

Comment: Biometric fee includes the VAC service charge BTW.